# How can I increment std::bitset

Tags: c++, biginteger, bitset

How can I achieve an increment on a `std::bitset<128>` in C++?

Because the bitset is 128 bits long, I cannot simply do

```
std::bitset<128> set = std::bitset<128>();

set = std::bitset<128>(set.to_ulong() + 1ULL);
```

Comment: You're trying to use a bitset to implement a large integer?

Comment: If you want big-integer-like behaviour, you should probably look into big-integer libraries.

Comment: You could do a ripple-add. It's simple enough to do. But I would suggest finding a library if you need big-int behavior. Why reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I am implementing the quadruple-precision floating point arithmetic of IEEE 754-2008, so generally using a big-int-library would be an option. Unfortunately using `bitset` is a given constraint for my task, though.

Comment: Why is there a constraint? Is this homework?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to agree with Oli, and say, if you want to do "big-integer" stuff, then you should use big integer library.

However, if you *really* want to do this using `std::bitset`, you'll need to do the arithmetic yourself.

```
template <size_t N>
std::bitset<N> increment ( std::bitset<N> in ) {
//  add 1 to each value, and if it was 1 already, carry the 1 to the next.
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i ) {
        if ( in[i] == 0 ) {  // There will be no carry
            in[i] = 1;
            break;
            }
        in[i] = 0;  // This entry was 1; set to zero and carry the 1
        }
    return in;
    }

int main () {
    std::bitset<32> foo;
    std::cout << foo.to_ulong () << ' ';
    foo = increment ( foo );
    std::cout << foo.to_ulong () << ' ';
    foo = increment ( foo );
    std::cout << foo.to_ulong () << ' ';
    foo = increment ( foo );
    std::cout << foo.to_ulong () << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This prints `0 1 2 3` for me.

Comment: I never did like the fact that the C and C++ languages don't have support for the Carry bit like assembly languages do.

Comment: Since I cannot use a big-integer library, I accepted this solution, which does the job.

Comment: If i am right, the decrement is:
        if ( in[i] == 1 ) { 
            in[i] = 0;
            break;
            }
        in[i] = 1; 
    }

Answer (score 2):

The trouble with the code above is in this line in particular:

```
set = std::bitset<128>(set.to_ulong() + 1ULL);
```

Unsigned long [ulong] is at least a 32-bit type in C++, depending on the OS + chipset, so in trying to cast a 128-bit variable into a this type you've created a small problem (without an implementation of a larger type, that is).

All is not lost.  As @Oli Charlesworth mentioned above, you can use a bigint library, and they are plentiful.  A decent one I've used before is [here](https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/).

For what you're trying to do above, you might try subbing the to_ulong() function in the context of a big integer library, something like to_bigint() which operates on a bitset.

Hope this helps.

Comment: 'unsigned long` is **at least** 32 bits.

Comment: `unsigned long` is not limited to 32 or 64 bits. It is **at least** 32 bits.